# Python code with arrays/dictionaries doesn't do what I expect

Tags: python

I'm writing a set of tools for Deezer. The one I'm working on right now will cycle through specified playlists and should report back if an album was found in multiple playlists.

I've tried various variations, working with arrays and dictionaries, but it never goes the way I intend it to work.

```
for count in range(len(playlists_tracks)):
    album_name = playlists_tracks[count]["album"]["title"]
    album_id = playlists_tracks[count]["album"]["id"]
    if album_name not in albums:
        albums[album_name] = playlist_name
        playlist_dupe[album_name] = playlist_name
        print ("New: " + album_name + " in " + playlist_name)
    elif album_name in albums and album_name not in playlist_dupe:
        playlist_dupe[album_name] = playlist_name
        albums_dupe[album_name] = albums[album_name] + " + " + playlist_name
        print ("Dupe: " + album_name + " in " + playlist_name)
    else:
      pass
```

The code above will go through all playlists (three in this example), but doesn't report back the right playlists. The album "1930" should be in playlist 1 + 2 + 3, but it only says 1 + 3. The albums after say the album exists in 2 + 2 (which is true, but it shouldn't output it). I have the full code on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/r0JMcGwm).

Example:

```
[('1930', 'Various Artists_Part1 + Various Artists_Part3'), ('4 Women No Cry', 'Various Artists_Part2 + Various Artists_Part2'), ('4 Women No Cry Vol. 3', 'Various Artists_Part2 + Various Artists_Part2')
```

Comment: Could you add the precise example output you are getting vs the one you expect? (pastebin not accessible from here...)

Comment: Whenever you create a new album you also add it to `playlist_dupe` so the conditoin `album_name in albums and album_name not in playlist_dupe` is **always** `False`. Remove the line `playlist_dupe[album_name] = ...` from the body of the `if`.

Comment: totally unrelated, but you may want to learn how to properlu use python's for loops : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: And string formatting too https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting